# Play Framework messages in controller

Tags: playframework

How can I access a value from the "messages" file in a controller?

For example, in my "messages" file:

```
app.name = Play Framework App
```

How can I get the value of `app.name` in a Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it with following code

```
Messages.get("app.name")
```

Also see http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/i18n#retrieve